# Reputation boosting

Tags: discussion

Can we stop up-voting questions about google's UX, like "why Google has a button" or "why Google has no button.."?

Nobody knows why until Google tells it publicly, and when Google does, it's available for everyone. Some Google UX related questions have 100 up-votes! Really? "Why does Google have a search button" question has 100 up-votes?

Answer (score 3):

This has already been covered in a more general sense by this question: [Should "Why does x company do...."or "Is there a reason why x does y" questions be removed?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1268/should-why-does-x-company-do-or-is-there-a-reason-why-x-does-y-questions)

But as for Google-specific ones: Such questions should be - and are - flagged and put on hold as being 'Primarily Opinion Based'.

If all we can do is speculate on the reasoning behind why Company X has done something then that can only mean we would be giving our opinions on it rather than *the* answer.

Some questions are not so black-and-white though. Using Google (and other sites) as examples of a behaviour you are querying for use in a separate instance is not necessarily off-topic. But yes, asking 'Why does company X do {thing}' is. Please flag or close these if you see them and they will be handled by the rest of the community.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't notice this subject was raised before.

Comment: @IvanVenediktov it's a bit of a quiet but omnipresent issue that pops up once and again any time one of such questions gets really popular. It's a problem when it's very high on the "interesting" scale but exceedingly low on the "useful" scale.

Comment: @BenBrocka I agree with you on "interesting" and "useful" scales. It is just very frustrating when a question as useless as "why does google have a button" gains such popularity. Makes you question the trustworthiness of the community.

Comment: @IvanVenediktov I don't think it's about trustworthiness. More an issue of 'bikeshed' questions. It's a problem for all SE sites. See this meta post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bikeshed-problem-and-stack-exchange. (Also [this wikipedia article on the Law of Triviality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality) is a good read too).

Comment: @JonW I can see this situation is not something new. Thanks for the article, I enjoyed reading it. Do you think there is a solution?

Comment: @IvanVenediktov Part of how StackExchange platform operates does provide a solution, to a degree. Namely that you can only gain a daily maximum reputation. So hugely popular questions don't reward massive amounts of reputation, because once you hit 200 rep a day then that's all you get, even if you get another 50 upvotes. Over a few days the question popularity dies down.

Comment: This is really satisfying, I didn't realise there was a cap on daily reputation.